# LNK1104 cannot open file 'legacy_stdio_definitions.lib'

Tags: visual-c++

I've ported my project from vs 2015 to vs 2013.

The Library i'm consuming is also built from vs 2015.

LNK1104     cannot open file 'legacy_stdio_definitions.lib'

What this error is all about?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need **legacy_stdio_definitions.lib** for programs built with Visual Studio 2013 or earlier versions. Just remove the library. The functions in this library are provided in other Visual Studio 2013 (and earlier) libraries.

[Here is a description of why this library is sometimes needed for programs built with Visual Studio 2015 and later.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/overview-of-potential-upgrade-issues-visual-cpp?view=vs-2015#libraries)